# When AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonAudioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient is occured AVCaptureSession is not recording video in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, ios-camera

During AVCaptureSession is running, when a phone call is occurred I get the interruption with reason **AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonAudioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient** and I called [captureSession beginConfiguration] and remove AVCaptureDeviceInput of AVMediaTypeAudio with lastly [captureSession commitConfiguration] and [captureSession startRunning] but I am unable to record video with output as AVCaptureMovieFileOutput. Pls help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem while using GPUImage. Following code did the work:
First remove audio outputs and inputs:

```
[_captureSession beginConfiguration];
[_captureSession removeInput:audioInput];
[_captureSession removeOutput:audioOutput];
audioInput = nil;
audioOutput = nil;
_microphone = nil;
[_captureSession commitConfiguration];
```

Then restart session

```
[_captureSession startRunning];
```

I think the part you are missing is removing output.